# How can I set my menu in center of whole screen using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted the menu in center using navbar. Is it possible to do it?

`HTML`:

```
    <header class="header-area">
        <nav class="header-nav navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-inline text-center">
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/logo1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="website-logo" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

`CSS`:

```
.header-area {
    background: url("images/background1.jpg") no-repeat 0 0 / 100% 100%;
    color: #84828D;
}
.header-nav .nav.navbar-nav {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    float: inherit;
}
```

***Here's is a sample picture :***
[image: Sample]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increase width here

```
.header-nav .nav.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    float: inherit;
}
```

And add following CSS

```
.navbar .nav, .navbar .nav > li {
  float:none;
  display:inline-block;
  *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
  *zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-inner {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Note: you have `**` here inside class,

```
<nav class="header-nav navbar**">**
```

it should be be

```
<nav class="header-nav navbar">**
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jvvLw35s/)

Comment: I have a question on it.Why you used display: inline-block in css?why not other property?Sorry for disturbance....... @Shehary

Comment: so the menu links comes inline next to other, if `display:block` menu links comes underneath the other, you can try  in the fiddle, make change and run the fiddle to see the effects of changes.

Comment: in simple inline-block means elements effected by this property sharing the block with other elements in same block but if only block means the element effected by this property don't want to share the space and kick others outside of it's space :)